# a word meaning 'making up for an absence'

Tags: single-word-requests

As in "If you were here you could have done something to prevent this catastrophe, but you weren't. Now you'll need to make up for your absence, and fix this mess"

Comment: Are you looking for a single-word or a phrase? A noun or an adjective? Can you provide a sentence where you would use the word?

Comment: You have to redeem yourself by fixing this mess? I can't figure out exactly without more content. Expiate? Not that I have ever used that word.

Comment: Since posting I have thought of 'atone' which is better than 'make up for'. 'Negligent' gets to the fault, but you can be negligent and present.

"I will atone for my negligence" or "I will atone for my absence" are ok, but this person wouldn't have to atone for being absent *if there weren't negative consequences to that abscence* i.e. if this person had been absent and nothing happened, he wouldn't have to atone, while the sentence "I will atone for my absence" could be read as that the atonement is for the absence itself.

Comment: "I will atone for the consequences of my abscence"

"I will _______"

Comment: Maybe "pick up the pieces" or "pick up the slack"?

Answer (score 0):

I will *atone* for my absence *by* putting in extra hours before going out of town.

That last part should take care of the concern you expressed at the end of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, but you leave it to users to read between the lines, to fill in the blanks, to guess your context ... but I'll give it a try ...

Your example:

> "If you were here you could have done something to prevent this
>   catastrophe, but you weren't. Now you'll need to make up for your
>   absence, and fix this mess"

The word that comes to mind is *redemption*. The person who wasn't there, but in your mind should have been, had to have been, needs to *redeem* themself, if that's even possible.

M-W:

> [*redeem*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redeem): to atone
>   for : expiate ; to offset the bad effect of

Your example again:

> "If you were here you could have done something to prevent this
>   catastrophe, but you weren't. Now you'll need to *redeem yourself* and fix this mess"

Answer (score 0):

You may use ***redress*** in this situation (it is broader than just "make up for absence" and actually also includes "fixing the mess").

> "If you were here you could have done something to prevent this
>   catastrophe, but you weren't. Now you'll need to ***redress*** this mess".

M-W:

> **[redress](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redress)**
>   *transitive verb*
>   **1 a (1)** :  to **set right** :  remedy : *looked to charity, not to legislation, to redress social wrongs — W. R. Inge* **(2)** :  to
>   **make up** for :  **compensate**
>   **b** :  to remove the cause of (a grievance or complaint)
>
> It is time to redress the injustices of the past.
>
> the belief that redressing a murder with another murder, even if
>   carried out by the state, is not morally justified